# Disable always on lock screen on the pixel 2

Tags: lock-screens, google-pixel-2

How can one disable always on lock screen on the pixel 2?

Comment: It would be much better if you elaborate problem in few more words like what exactly you mean by always on lock screen and also if you could add a screenshot ☺

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are talking about Ambient display. If so, you can go to:

Settings -> Display -> Advanced -> Ambient display -> Toggle "Always on"